# guardar excel en MySQL y eliminar uno ya existente

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy guardando un archivo de excel en MySQL mediante un jsp en java. ¿Cómo hago para que al momento de guardar otro archivo de excel en la misma base de datos me elimine el archivo ya existente y me lo reemplace por el nuevo?

Adjunto el código de la clase donde leo el excel y donde lo guardo en MySQL

```
public class ReadExcel2 {

    public static void leerArchivoExcel2(FileInputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int con = 1;
        String nombre_ant = "";

        Row fila;
        List<TablaJira> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        TablaJira ji = null;

        for (int i = 1; i < firstSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

            fila = firstSheet.getRow(i);

            ji = new TablaJira();

            for (int j = 0; j < fila.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                Cell celda = fila.getCell(j);

                if (j == 0) {

                    if (celda == null || celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                switch (j) {

                    case 0:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setProyecto(celda.getStringCellValue());

                        }

                        //   n.setNovedad(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setTipo(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        //ne.setFecha_inicio(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setClave(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        //ne.setFecha_fin(celda.getStringCellValue());

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setTitulo(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }
                        //ne.setAño(celda.getStringCellValue());

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            ji.setNombres(celda.getStringCellValue());

                            // System.out.println(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        }

                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (celda.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                            ji.setTiempo_horas((int) celda.getNumericCellValue());
                        }

                        //else if (celda.getCellType()== Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                        //ne.setHoras(celda.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Se guardan los datos por cada fila
            //guardarTablaNovedadEmpleado(ne);
            //guardarTablaNovedades(n);
            if (ji.getNombres() != null) {
                lst.add(ji);

            }

        }

        Collections.sort(lst, TablaJira.comparet);

        // en este for se esta asiendo la comparacion de los nombres para reiniciar
        //los id por cada nombre diferente
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {

            String nombre = lst.get(i).getNombres();

            if (nombre == null ? nombre_ant != null : !nombre.equals(nombre_ant)) {
                con = 1;
                               lst.get(i).setPosicion(con);

                nombre_ant = nombre;
            } else {
                con++;
                lst.get(i).setPosicion(con);

            }

        }

        lst.forEach(ReadExcel2::guardarTblJira);

    }

    private static void guardarTblJira(TablaJira ji) {
        TablaJiraDao dao = new TablaJiraDao();
        dao.insertarTablaJira(ji);

    }

    /* private static void guardarTablaNovedadEmpleado(TablaNovedadEmpleado ne) {
        TablaNovedadEmpleadoDao dao = new TablaNovedadEmpleadoDao();
        dao.insertarTablaNovedadEmpleado(ne);
    }

    private static void guardarTablaNovedades(TablaNovedades n) {
        TablaNovedadesDao dao = new TablaNovedadesDao();
        dao.insertarTablan(n);//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }*/
}
```

y donde lo guardo

```
/**
 *
 * @author pcc
 */
public class TablaJiraDao {

    public int insertarTablaJira(TablaJira ji) {
        int bandera = 0;
        Conexion con = null;
        try {
            con = new Conexion();
            String query = "INSERT INTO tbljira (posicion , proyecto , tipo , clave , titulo , nombres , tiempo_horas) values (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )";
            PreparedStatement st = con.getConn().prepareStatement(query);
            // Empieza desde 1, cada número coresponde a la posición de cada signo de interrogación (?)
            //  st.setString(1, r.getNro_Documento());
            st.setInt(1, ji.getPosicion());
            st.setString(2, ji.getProyecto());
            st.setString(3, ji.getTipo());
            st.setString(4, ji.getClave());
            st.setString(5, ji.getTitulo());
            st.setString(6, ji.getNombres());
            st.setInt(7, ji.getTiempo_horas());

            bandera = st.executeUpdate();

            //System.out.println ("El archivo se a guardado exitosamente");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(TablaJiraDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        }
        return bandera;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que ver en base a qué campo de la tabla tbljira se agrupan los registros a borrar y hacer una delete sobre esa tabla.

```
String query = "DELETE FROM tbljira where proyecto=? and clave=?";
PreparedStatement st = con.getConn().prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(1, ji.getProyecto());
st.setString(2, ji.getClave());
st.executeUpdate();
```

Los campos de la where no sé si serán esos, que no has explicado el modelo de tu base de datos.
Una vez hecho eso, realiza la llamada a insertarTablaJira y listo.